# override transaction timeout at a statement level

Tags: jdbc, transactions, ibatis, distributed-transactions

My ibatis configuration uses an XA datasource and JTA transaction manager.
Is it possible to override the transaction timeout at a statement level.

I tried the options suggested here: [Specify IBatis query timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866045/specify-ibatis-query-timeout). It does not work.

A particular SQL in my application is a long running query and it times out after the timeout no. of seconds set in weblogic JTA config.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transaction manager can't iterrupt you running code. So transaction timeout dosn't affect time of your queries execution.  After execution  of your code  will be completed Transaction manager will decide to rollback your transaction if transaction timeout was exceeded.